# Does charisma affect buying prices for items in book return terminals?

Tags: fallout-4

It affects bartering with vendors, but does it affect buy prices for book return terminals? I'm using a character who can have up to 17 charisma, but said charisma doesn't seem to affect the prices displayed on the terminal (50 tokens for a fusion core, about 15 for a telephone, etc., seems unchanged).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charisma affects only other people/creatures.  You can't charm a vending machine to sell you something for cheaper via charismatic means since it's inanimate. The [Wiki page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Overdue_book) makes no mention of this for the book return terminals, nor does the [Charisma page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Charisma).  From my experience, I've witness the same as you have.

Looking at this from an in real life perspective, you might be able to charm someone into selling you something for cheaper.  It makes sense that the book return terminal isn't influenced by such means, since they can't experience feelings.

Comment: What about [KL-E-O](http://fallout4.wiki.fextralife.com/KL-E-O), the robotic NPC that is a merchant in Goodneighbor?  Your logic would suggest the Charisma skill doesn't affect prices with just this one vendor, but I highly doubt that is the case.  I'm pretty sure Charisma will improve prices with KL-E-O as well.

Comment: @GeneralMike I was considering all merchants in the game including the robotic ones. Yes my example would contradict it, but those are special exceptions to the case ;)

Comment: I personally would like to think that a hyper advanced war bot AI could experience feelings.